# Android GPS: altitude of metres

Tags: android, gps, height, sensors

I´m new in GPS Android programming and I want to make an app that tells me the exact altitude of metres, also when I move.

Unfortunately, I don´t know where to start. Which sensor do I need that it works on every mobile phone? And I already read that there are two ways, one exact and one not so correct. 
Please give me a start.

Comment: location.getAltitude() ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The GPS device delivers the altitude in meters above the WGS84 ellipsoid. The accuracy depends on the GPS satellite constellation and the current free-view to sky situation, but typically has an error of not better than 15-30m.

Please note that this vaue is not mean Sea Level, in europe that difference is e.g 6m to the mean sea level in Triest/Italy.
If you look at a modern paper map, then the deviation of WGS84 to the local valid mean sea level is specified.

All in all altitude via GPS is not very accurate for many applications. Thats the reason why professional outdoor Gps devices additionally have a barometer sensor included, to measure better relative altitude changes.

To get an acurate altitude you must send your location(latitude, longitude) to a/your server and look the corect altitude up in one of the huge digital elevation model files (DEM), provided by US government and post processed by some other institutions. (For a limited number of locations, there is also a google service)

For your first step, simply take the `altitude` from the provided `Location`.

(Note that devices without a GPS sensor might also give an altitude value, but this value could be related to a location e.g 1000m away.)

Comment: Ok, thank you. I will look at it and come back if I have a question. If not, I´ll accept the answer, thank you!